# CakePHP Data in Model as array not datatable

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, model

I have some data to share in application but its not that much that I should use a database table. I was wondering, can I create an array in model and then from Controllers getting data form that array?

I have some types of users on website. These users sometimes have different main page (other modules) and I want to create an array `$modules[userType][moduleArray];`

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Take a look at the [CakePHP cookbook entry on data sources](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html). You’ll want to create a private property to hold your data, and implement the read/write methods to pop/push to your array as appropriate.